# How to convert the list output of a function to vector

Tags: r

Suppose I have the following list of list.

```
tau1 <- rnorm(10,0,1)
tau2 <- rnorm(10,0,1)
tau <- list(tau1, tau2)
tau

tau3 <- rnorm(10, 0,1)
tau4 <- rnorm(10,0,1)
tau5 <- list(tau3, tau4)
tau5
```

Then, my following function returns a list of list.

```
Tau <- list(tau, tau5)
myfun <- function(Tau){
    m <- length(Tau[[1]])
    tau1 <- lapply(1:m, function(i) (Tau[[1]][[i]]+tau[[2]][[i]]))
    Tau1 <- lapply(1:m, function(i) Tau[[1]][[i]]/ (Reduce("+", tau1[[i]])))
    Tau2 <- lapply(1:m, function(i) Tau[[2]][[i]]/ (Reduce("+", tau1[[i]])))
    w1 <- lapply(1:m, function(i) mean(Tau1[[i]]))
    w2 <- lapply(1:m, function(i) mean(Tau2[[i]]))
    w <- list(w1, w2)
    return(w)
  }
```

The output is like this:

```
> myfun(Tau)
[[1]]
[[1]][[1]]
[1] -0.4593304

[[1]][[2]]
[1] -0.302662


[[2]]
[[2]][[1]]
[1] 1.45933

[[2]][[2]]
[1] 1.302662
```

I would like the output to be like this:

```
> myfun(Tau)
[[1]]
[1] -0.4593304.  -0.302662

[[2]]
[1] 1.45933  1.302662
```

any help, please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One approach would be to add unlist to your function:

```
myfun <- function(Tau){
  m <- length(Tau[[1]])
  tau1 <- lapply(1:m, function(i) (tau[[1]][[i]]+tau[[2]][[i]]))
  Tau1 <- lapply(1:m, function(i) tau[[1]][[i]]/ (Reduce("+", tau1[[i]])))
  Tau2 <- lapply(1:m, function(i) tau[[2]][[i]]/ (Reduce("+", tau1[[i]])))
  w1 <- unlist(lapply(1:m, function(i) mean(Tau1[[i]])))
  w2 <- unlist(lapply(1:m, function(i) mean(Tau2[[i]])))
  w <- list(w1, w2)
  return(w)
}

myfun(Tau) #the original version
#output
[[1]]
[1] -0.5441523  0.6246206

[[2]]
[1] 1.5441523 0.3753794
```

another is to do:

```
z <- myfun(Tau) #the original function 
lapply(z, unlist)
#output
[[1]]
[1] -0.5441523  0.6246206

[[2]]
[1] 1.5441523 0.3753794
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried `unlist` with the `recursive` option turned off? Hopefully this will work:

```
> tau2 <- unlist(Tau,recursive=FALSE)
> tau2
[[1]]
 [1] -0.37723765  0.09761946  1.63874465 -0.87559247  0.12176000  1.36213066 -0.23462109 -1.05338281
 [9] -0.86978361 -0.39012703

[[2]]
 [1] -0.84735007 -0.26063939 -0.41441971 -0.18305080  0.40705610  0.62463313  1.67820574 -0.06869365
 [9] -0.32083991  1.47100572

[[3]]
 [1]  1.70432940  0.04324404 -0.33265732 -1.82223542  1.41126240 -0.83758243 -1.12376279  3.04376589
 [9]  0.23502131 -0.03325861

[[4]]
 [1] -2.73221952 -0.09979059  0.97603173  0.41386892  0.91232216  1.98373220  1.16910851 -0.50873702
 [9]  0.70418018 -0.19841627
```